# Solve $AXB=X^\top$

Tags: matrices, control-theory

Suppose that $X$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, $A$ and $B$ are $n\times m$ matrices. How can you solve $$AXB=X^\top.$$

*Is there an explicit formulation of $X$ in terms of $A$ and $B$ that makes the above equation true?*

*Are there explicit formulations of $A$ and $B$ in terms of $X$ that make the above equation true?*

Comment: Based on your definition, the left side evaluates to an $m\times n$ matrix, but the right side is an $n\times m$ matrix. Therefore, it doesn't make sense as written.

Comment: This is in fact a special case of a [discrete-time Lyapunov equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation).

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you know how to [vectorize ("flatten") a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29) and what are [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and [commutation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix), the equation $AXB=X^T$ can be rewritten as
$$(B^T\otimes A-K^{(m,n)})\operatorname{vec}(X)=0,$$
which is just an ordinary system of $mn$ linear equations in $mn$ unknowns, but only larger in size.