# Can matrix transposition be represented by a sequence of matrix multiplications?

Tags: matrices, transpose

I think this thread seems to say no

[Can the matrix transpose be represented by $X^T = AXB$ for a given $A$ and $B$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2792538/can-the-matrix-transpose-be-represented-by-xt-axb-for-a-given-a-and-b)

What I am asking is that given X, do there exist any number of matrices, A1, A2,etc and multiplications such that

$\mathbf{X}^\intercal = ((\mathbf{X} *  \mathbf{A1}) * \mathbf{A2}) . . . $

or to get even more complex

$\mathbf{X}^\intercal = f(X,A1,A2...)$ where the function ,f is any combination of matrices and multiplications.

Why do I ask this? Because thelinear combination of matrices reminds me of the models used in deep learning. And so I began to wonder if a symbolic procedure (like matrix transposition) could be 'learned' by a deep learning model. Certainly I can try this. I already generated a million random 3x3 matrices with their transposes to use as a training set. I am uncertain as to how to structure the model (how many layers, etc) but there is no reason to suspect that such a model cannot be trained. Then I could give it any matrix and it would 'infer' the transpose. And this is where my brain fails me.

So if a deep learning model can provide an affirmative answer to this question whereas logical analysis says it is impossible, I am confronted with an interesting contradiction. Deep learning can solve a problem that logic cannot. But first I have to KNOW that matrix transposition CANNOT be symbolically represented as a combination of matrix multiplications.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know any deep learning stuffs, but this is very basic linear algebra. Suppose $X$ is $n\times m$. Then $X^T=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mE_{ji}XE_{ji}$ where $E_{ji}$ denotes the $m\times n$ matrix whose only nonzero entry is a $1$ at the $(j,i)$-th position. Thus the transposition of an $n\times m$ matrix is a rank-$nm$ tensor.

Comment: I am not asking for the definition of transposition. I am asking for a set of matrices and multiplication operations that result in transposition of the original matrix.

Comment: @aquagremlin As shown in my answer, if you pre- and post-multiply $X$ by the $E_{ji}$ and sum over each pair of $(i,j)$, you get $X^T$.